# How to git stash only untracked files?

Tags: git

I want to only stash all untracked files. I know it can be done with two commands, by first stashing tracked changes and then untracked, but can it be done with one line command?

Comment: How can you stash untracked files?

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky With `git stash -u`, you can include untracked files in the stash. `-u` is not compatible with `--patch`, so you cannot use the trick of of `stash --patch -u` and then saying yes to just the untracked ones.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do it with alias in [`~/.gitconfig`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases):

```sh
stash-untracked = "!f() {    \
    git stash;               \
    git stash -u;            \
    git stash pop stash@{1}; \
}; f"
```

And then just do

```sh
git stash-untracked
```

Comment: @Aurimas afaik `~/.gitconfig` aliases are added to bash autocompletion rules. so bash will be able to autocomplete that

Comment: My `~/gitconfig` looks like so: (and autocomplete is not working even after restart)

`[color]
  ui = true
[user]
  name = Aurimas Kubeldzis
  email = 4urimas@gmail.com
[credential]
  helper = cache --timeout=604800
[push]
  default = simple

stash-untracked = "!f() {    \
    git stash;               \
    git stash -u;            \
    git stash pop stash@{1}; \
}; f"`

Comment: @Aurimas there should be a dot in file name `~/.gitconfig` and alias should be placed after `[alias]` section

Comment: @vsminkov could you explain why I need a function, and what will the three commands do?

Answer (score 4):

### For Beginners (with example)

Imagine you are on branch `A`, but you want to commit only changes to existing files, while the newly created file should be committed to a new branch `B`.

##### Add script (by vsminkov) to `.git/config`

Inside the `.git` folder there is a `config` file. Open it up and you will see something like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
```

**change the config file to:**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[alias]
    stash-untracked = "!f() {    \
                git stash;               \
                git stash -u;            \
                git stash pop stash@{1}; \
            }; f"
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
```

Now you will be able to use the following command while you are on branch A.

```
git stash-untracked
```

You will see that the new file disappeared, if you are using a editor like VSCode (it's now stashed)

While still on branch A stage and commit the changes to the existing files:

```
git add .
git commit -m "committing tracked changes to current branch"
```

Next step is creating a new branch B (with `checkout -b` you visit it immediately)

```
git checkout -b newBranchName
```

When using `stash pop` the stashed changes get added to your current branch.

```
git stash pop
```

The only thing left is to stage and commit the changes on the new branch B

```
git add .
git commit -m "created new file"
```